# Is it possible to do a fragment caching in a rabl view?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, api, caching, rabl

I'm trying to do something like this:

```
cache "api/v1/cars_index/#{I18n.locale}/car/#{car.cache_key}" do
  attributes :id, :brand, :model_name, :fuel, :km, :year, :price
  node(:color) { |car| car.color.present? ? car.color : '' }
end
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For those people who finds this question through a search or google.

Niels started an issue on Github which can be found [here](https://github.com/nesquena/rabl/issues/143).

A developer created a great solution for this which has been merged into rabl since v0.6.2.

Comment: Cool - I wasn't aware that this has been solved :-D I'll implement straight away!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!